# Google Maps Api v3: Map's center jumps to the added Marker

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I got a bit of a problem. I want to display a route between two points and give custom markers to both points. It is working.

- I set suppressMarkers = true
- I call directionsService.route to display the route.
- The map's center is correct, the whole route fits into my map's canvas beautifully.
- Then I add custom markers to both origin and destination.

Then comes the problem: When I add the custom markers, the map's center jumps to the last added marker. I want to keep the map's center on the route, that was originally generated by the directionsService.route function.

PS: Weirdly if I add the markers before displaying the route, the map still centers on the last added marker.

Thanks,

Pál Terebess

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Well I have to simplify the code I have 2 functions that add markers and another that makes the route:

Comment: http://pastebin.com/iCgyNja0

Answer (score 0):

One option to try would be save the Bounds (using getBounds) of the map after generating the route and reapply it after adding the markers (using setBounds).

Edit: setBounds isn't a function. Maybe try either fitBounds or getting the zoom and center and resetting those.

Comment: It is strange, because getBounds returns the proper data: a set a long and lat attributes. But Firefox's JS console says setBounds doesn't exist.

So I CAN retrieve the bound(s) I prefer to display, but I am unable to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, sorry. I just found the bug this morning. I used setcenter when adding the markers. It works perfectly now. Thank you for your time guys! I am greatful nevertheless.